# Misunderstanding in dimensions. I do not get why NN does not accept dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have problem with dimensions understanding
[image]

Comment: Please don't share image of the code as it's not helpful. And have a clear description of the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform image layout.

Model expects: **(batch, channels, height, width)**

But you provide: **(height, width, channels)**

So you need to change layout and add batch dimension

```
model(X.permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0))
```

or numpy version:

```
a = a.transpose(2, 0, 1)[np.newaxis]
```